# Invoke a filter before spring security filter chain in boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have configured my filter as below but it doesn't get invoked before Spring Security Filter chain.  I have set the order as zero

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3 which support setting order on filter

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {

  FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

  registrationBean.setFilter(new UrlRewriteFilter());
  registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("*");
  registrationBean.addInitParameter("confReloadCheckInterval", "5");
  registrationBean.addInitParameter("logLevel", "DEBUG");
  registrationBean.addInitParameter("confPath", "urlrewrite.xml");
  registrationBean.setOrder(0);

  return registrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**application.properties**

```
security.filter-order=5
//>spring 2.1.3
spring.security.filter-order=5
```

These properties change from time to time and can be found here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#actuator-properties

I haven't done this myself but looking at the code it appears you simply need to set a property for the order of the security filter. For example in application.properties

This should order your filter before the security filter. I don't know what the implications are of changing this order as far as security goes it feels a bit risky to me. There is a discussion amongst the Spring developers about this here. It ends up in them implementing what my answer was above.

Discussion

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640

Test showing what this property does.(search for testCustomFilterOrder())

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.2.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityAutoConfigurationTests.java

Comment: Thank you Zergleb for providing the solution.  Adding "security.filter-order=5" in application.properties did the trick

Comment: Thanks, note in Spring Boot 2.1.3 the property is:  spring.security.filter.order=5

Comment: The answer regarding `regBean.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 1);` seems a bit safer?

Answer (score 7):

The best way I have found to do this in SpringBoot 2.0 is in your Spring Security Configuration using addFilterBefore. I chose to do it before the Username Password filter as my filter was an alternative login filter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new UrlRewriteFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/*/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't feel like choosing an arbitrary order for the security filter chain in the **application.properties** file, you can set the order using the **SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER** value. This is the value used by the security filter chain since it doesn't explicitly set an order value.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> regBean= new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    regBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    regBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    // Invoke MyFilter before the security filter chain
    regBean.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 1);

    return regBean;
}
```