# How do I create load order for for Filters in AutoConfiguration PRIOR to loading into SpringSecurityFilterChain in demo-project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security, spring-autoconfiguration

I am trying to create a load order in the autoconfiguration for the following filters:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestParamsFilter> requestParamsFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<RequestParamsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new RequestParamsFilter(principle, apiCacheService));
    registrationBean.setOrder(1)
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}


@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ParamsMarshallerFilter> paramsMarshallerFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<ParamsMarshallerFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new ParamsMarshallerFilter(buildProperties, ctx, apiProperties));
    registrationBean.setOrder(2)
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Unfortunately, in the demo project, once the SecurityConfig creates a SpringSecurityFilterChain, I have to create the load order THERE (like so):

```
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(paramsMarshallerFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(requestParamsFilter, ParamsMarshallerFilter.class);
```

Is there a way to set the load order for a SpringSecurityFilterChain in an autoconfiguration PRIOR to loading into the project??

**NOTE** : I have tried setOrder and the @Order annotation (to no effect); my only other solution is to cram all functionality into ONE FILTER to avoid bad ordering. But I am SURE Spring would never break OOP and force me to do this... right??? :/ *fingers crossed*

Comment: so you want to "execute" ("loading" is confusing/happens only once) "your custom filter" before spring security filter (chain)?  [like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34229750/592355)

Comment: Yeah I tried that in the application.properties for the autoconfiguration. That doesn't work because it is not 'executing' since it is an autoconfiguration. AFAIK, autoconfiguration files don't execute until used by the implemented application (see dependencies/starters in gradle or maven)

Comment: Please note again that "I am trying to create a load order in the autoconfiguration". Applications load 'starters' which use autoconfigurations. The 'autoconfiguration' itself is not an app but more of a 'plugin'. This is the problem that I am running into... that I am trying to set the load order for filters loaded in the auto configuration file.